# I want to set level with in time interval in array form

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, momentjs, linechart

I am using angular js and moment.js. Right now I am generating levels for line graph. So I need to set some levels for x axis values. I want to set hours interval in x'axis. Right now I am using these(x'aix) values statically, But now I want to set dynamically with javascript function.

```
var lineData = { labels: ["0hr", "1hr", "2hr", "3hr", "4hr", "5hr", "6hr"],
                datasets: [                   
                    {
                        label: "My Second dataset",
                        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",                      
                        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                        data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 80]
                    }
                ]
            }; 
 var startFromTime=11;
 var endToTime=15;
```

I want to set time interval from 11 to 15 in labels.

> labels: ["0hr", "1hr", "2hr", "3hr", "4hr", "5hr", "6hr"]

[image]

can I set assign these value in array form to variable and this variable assign into labels:[1,2,3,4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need moment.JS for this rather a plain old JavaScript function would do the job.

```
function getTimeLabels(start) {
var timeStart = start;
var limit = 7;

var resultArr = [];
var counter = 0;

for (var x = 0; x < (timeStart + limit); x++) {

    if (x > 24) {
        resultArr.push(counter + "hr");
    }
    resultArr.push(x + "hr");
}

return resultArr;
}
```

Here you pass the number you wish to start at and it will generate your labels, it also takes into account when x goes over 24 and uses a different counter to finish operations occurring after.

your code modified:

```
var lineData = { labels: getTimeLabels(0),
                datasets: [                   
                    {
                        label: "My Second dataset",
                        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",                      
                        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                        data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 80]
                    }
                ]
            }; 
 var startFromTime=11;
 var endToTime=15;
```

Comment: What is the limit=7?

Comment: Thanks . But I want to plot x axis values. If I selected start time 5 and ending time 13hrs then it have to plot 5,     6,    7,  8,   9, 10, 11,12,13.

Comment: The limit is the amount of places it will move, you could alternatively add another parameter in as limit and us that to move more places.